# Why var prezzo doesn't refresh value?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, var

I can't understand the reason why moving the slider on 12, var prezzo doesn't refresh value and doesn't display 100. Thank in advance to everybody would help me

```js
      var prezzo ="0";
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = prezzo;
    
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo1");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
    if (slider==12) {
    prezzo = "100";
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="12" max="36" value="24" step="12" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Km: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
  <p>Prezzo: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second line copies the value of the variable to the innerHTML property. It does not create a reference to the variable.

When you later change the value of the variable, you aren’t changing the value of innerHTML. If you want to do that, then you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, can you show me the right code to solve this issue please? 
thank you in  advance